# How to get email using spring social plugin org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook

Tags: spring-boot

I am able to access name using

```
facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getName()
```

But if i access the following code it returning null value

```
facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getEmail()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the "email" scope.

Padd the scope to the `/auth/facebook` endpoint

```
th:href="@{/auth/facebook(scope='email')}"
```

Comment: Yes. I am using scope as email as below:                                       **<form action="/connect/facebook" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="email" />
     <div class="formInfo">
     <p>You aren't connected to Facebook yet. Click the button to    connect this application with your Facebook account.</p>
     </div>
     <p><button type="submit">Connect to Facebook</button></p>
</form>**